# java.util.logging how to avoid turning off logging for a child level

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a class `TestClass` in a package `com.logtests`. I have attached a log handler for `TestClass` and set log level to ALL for `com.logtests.TestClass`. I have a handler at `com.logtests` level also. This works fine.

Now when I set log level to OFF at `com.logtests`, it is turning off logging at `com.logtests.TestClass` also. As I have set a separate handler at lower level, I was expecting the log handler at `com.logtests.TestClass` to continue to write log.

So my question is: How can I ensure the lower level class continues to log even if logging at parent level is turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [java.util.logging.Logger.setLevel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setLevel-java.util.logging.Level-) documentation:

> If the new level is null, it means that this node should inherit its level from its nearest ancestor with a specific (non-null) level value.

If you declare an exact level for your child logger then it will not inherit the level from the parent logger.

```
com.logtests.level=OFF
com.logtests.TestClass.level=ALL
```

If you are setting the level in your code then order of operations matter.  The parent logger must be set to `OFF` before the child logger is set to `ALL`.

```
public class EffectiveLevel {

    private static final Logger PARENT = Logger.getLogger("com.logtests");
    private static final Logger CHILD = Logger.getLogger("com.logtests.TestClass");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PARENT.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        CHILD.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        System.out.println(PARENT.getName() + " " + PARENT.getLevel());
        System.out.println(CHILD.getName() + " " + CHILD.getLevel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delayed response. Since the logger level is set on the fly, if I set com.logtests.TestClass.level=ALL and then set logger level for com.logtests.level = OFF, then logging at com.logtests.TestClass is also turned off.

Comment: @Shashi  What happens when you swap the order of those two statements?